# Fixed range for y-axis in Swift Charts

Tags: swiftui, charts, ios16

I want that my y-axis always shows a range from 0-60 even though there are data sets that do not represent the full range.
E.g. if I'm showing a data set with values of just 10 and 40 the y-axis range is only from 0-40 instead of 0-60.

Any ideas how to configure the y-axis for Swift Charts (iOS 16) with a fixed range?

```
Chart { 
        ForEach(model.series.entries, id: \.weekday) { element in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Day", element.weekday, unit: .day),
                y: .value("Feeling", element.value)
            )
        }
    }
    .chartXAxis {
        let unit: Calendar.Component = model.resolution == .yearly ? .month : .day
        
        AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: unit, count: 1)) { _ in
            AxisGridLine()
            AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(.narrow), centered: true)
        }
    }
```

[image: Content with values of 40 and 50]

[image: Content with values of 10 and 40]

Comment: add this to your Chart, `.chartYScale(domain: 0...60) `

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine That's exactly what I need for my y-axis scale. However, I'm facing a different problem now. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: There are too many missing parts to test your code (and any answers). Show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine sry my bad. everything works fine, I made a typo and let the domain start with 10 instead of 0. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try adding this to your Chart, `...to configure the y-axis for Swift Charts (iOS 16) with a fixed range`:

```
.chartYScale(domain: 0...60)
```

Comment: How can I make it custom?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi I was just kinda dumb everything worked xD

Answer (score 1):

While looking for a way to zoom into a fractional range, I came across this solution. This solution wasn't suitable for me though, since my y-values fluctuate between 0.1 and 0.8, and I specifically wanted to focus on the 0.5 to 0.7 range. To do this, I used an array of two elements specifying the desired y-range limits:

```swift
.chartYScale(domain: [0.5, 0.7])
```

This slightly more general solution also works for the above problem:

```swift
.chartYScale(domain: [0, 60])
```